# Easy way to parse ASCII plist files in PHP

Tags: php, xcode, parsing, plist

I'm trying to deal with data from a legacy system, which seems to be in [ASCII plist format](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html). Is there an easy method to parse these or convert them to an easier to deal with format? Ideally, the output should be nested arrays. (These files are also used by [GNUstep](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php?title=Property_Lists) and for XCode project files)

A [library](https://github.com/PonyCui/ascii-plist-decoder) exists, but their sample fails even with Apple's sample of a NSDictionary: (My yacc / lex knowledge is not sufficient to quickly try and fix that...) (It fails for any unquoted values or key names)

Apple's sample file:

```
{
    AnimalSmells = { pig = piggish; lamb = lambish; worm = wormy; };
    AnimalSounds = { pig = oink; lamb = baa; worm = baa;
                    Lisa = "Why is the worm talking like a lamb?"; };
    AnimalColors = { pig = pink; lamb = black; worm = pink; };
}
```

The available libraries for plist files seems to only support XML and binary plist files, not ASCII ones.

Implementing a full library for parsing some output from a legacy system in one place seems like overkill...

An ugly approach seen in some other (non-PHP) code that I've seen, is to use regular expressions to modify the data until other methods can parse it.

---

For the linked library:

In the [Lexer](https://github.com/PonyCui/ascii-plist-decoder/blob/master/src/AsciiPlist/Lexer.plex), this is likely part of the problem:

```
stringliteral = /\"(\\.|[^\\\"])*\"/
```

(Strings are required to be quoted) (The library seems to be written for a specific use case, and my use case seems quite far from that...)

Compiling the lexer with [plex](https://github.com/pear/PHP_LexerGenerator) also results in different source file, which makes randomly modifying to see what happens tricky...

Answer (score 0):

It *almost* looks like JSON! You could try doing a string replace?

`replace = with :`
`replace ; with ,`
`replace ; } with }` // semicolon space closed_curly

Then you can `json_decode($string);` it into an array!

If that feels hacky to you, try a library such as https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList

Good luck!

Comment: CFPropertyList only support binary and XML plist files according to the documentation, not the pre-OS X (NEXTSTEP timeframe) ASCII ones...

Comment: That seems more useful... (Very undocumented, but it actually parses my data... That in answer format can be useful)

Comment: (The json_decode() method suffers from the same flaw as the ascii-plist-decoder library - the key names and all the values needs to be quoted...)